# Easy way to detect first-middle-last item

Tags: php

I have a site with a grid of photos. Every item should get its own css. I have `first`, `middle` and `last`. I wrote a PHP-snippet which does the trick, but it's quite limited and very scale-unfriendly.

```
$firstItem = array(1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49);
if (in_array($key, $firstItem)) {
    echo '<div class="photoblock first">';
}
$secondItem = array(2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50);
if (in_array($key, $secondItem)) {
    echo '<div class="photoblock middle">';
}
$thirdItem = array(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48);
if (in_array($key, $thirdItem)) {
    echo 'div class="photoblock last">';
}
```

As you can see, once I have more then 50 pictures, I need to refill the array... Is there an easier way how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something as (pseudo-code):

```
if ($key % 3 == 1) // Is a first item
if ($key % 3 == 2) // This as a middle item
if ($key % 3 == 0) // ...and last
```

`A % B` is the modulus operator, it gives you the rest of the division of A by B. For example 22 % 7 -> 1, because 7 * 3 = 21, 22 - 21 = 1.

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator (`%`) is your friend here.

```
$positions = array('first', 'middle', 'last');    

foreach($items as $index => $item) {

    $position = $positions[$index % 3];

    echo 'div class="photoblock ' . $position . '">';

}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/LhUAcxUz).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use math?

```
if ($key % 3 == 1) {
    echo '<div class="photoblock first">';
} elseif ($key % 3 == 2) {
    echo '<div class="photoblock middle">';
} elseif ($key % 3 == 0) {
    echo '<div class="photoblock last">';
}
```

According to the php docs:

```
Modulus
$a % $b
Remainder of $a divided by $b
```

Another way to think of this is that all the numbers that were in your first array (1,4,7,..) are all "multiples of 3, plus 1" (0*3+1=1, 1*3+1=4, 2*3+1=7, etc...). That's where the "3" and the "1" come in the condition. Similarly, all the numbers in the second set are "multiples of 3, plus 2", and all the numbers in the last group are "multiples of 3, plus 0".